# How to check a function whether it is of bounded variation or not in an open interval.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

How to check a function whether it is of bounded variation  or not in an open interval.

$f(x) = \sqrt{(1 - x^2)}$   Is this function of bounded variation on  $x \in (-1,1)$?

My thought: I know how to check it in $[-1,1]$. This function will be monotone on both the interval $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$.So this will be of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I have an idea... Take $ε>0$ and let the interval be $[-1+ε, 1-ε]$. Now proceed in the same way.

Comment: That is known to me. Please read my  thought part. But it can not be applied in an open interval as we do not have the end points which are necessary to define partition.@copper.hat

Comment: What is your definition of total variation on an open interval?  If you look at the definition given [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Function_of_bounded_variation#Generalizations) you'll see that you've already proved your function is of bounded variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f'(x)=-2x\frac 1 {2\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}$ is integrable on $(-1,1)$ so the total variation of $f$ on  $(-1,1)$ does not exceed $\int_{-1}^{1} |f'(x)|\, dx$.

Comment: Can you please explain what is your definition of total variation on an open interval?@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Total variation of $f$ on $(-1,1)$ is supremum of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} |f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)|$ ever all choices of $n$ and $x_k$'s with $-1<x_1<x_2<...x_n<1$. I have not seen this definition in a  text book, but this is the most natural way of defining total variation on an open interval which takes care of oscillations near the end points.